# C# How can I best create a 'New Project' option from File menu

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have an application that effectively manages workflow on files in a set of predefined folders on a shared drive. i.e users can check files out and check them in and move them to QA etc, which phisically moves the files within the predefined folder structure.

However, at the moment this will obviously only work with a single project (and the single set of folders that i have coded into the program).

What i'd like to be able to do, is have a File menu item that is 'Create new Project'. When selected, a dialog box pops up asking for the project name and maybe a couple of other bits of info, then it creates the folder structure for that new project and away i go.

The user obviously also needs the option to choose which project to work with, and therefore which folder structure.

I have no idea where to start with this, so any pointers would be very useful. Thanks in advance

Comment: Have a look at this [Visual Studio Tip: Create Your Own Project Templates](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2012/09/17/create-your-own-vs-project-templates.aspx)

Comment: Are you talking about VS integration or want to create a gui? http://officeribbon.codeplex.com/

Comment: I have created a GUI for the existing program using listViews etc. which list the files in various folders and list their workflow state. It's the implementation of the different project option that i'm struggling to understand how to do.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using, **The Managed Package Framework (MPF)** provides C# classes you can use or inherit from to implement your own project types. The MPF implements many of the interfaces Visual Studio expects a project type to provide, leaving you free to concentrate on implementing the particulars of your project type. # [Courtesy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb166157.aspx)

## [MPF for Projects - Visual Studio 2010](http://mpfproj10.codeplex.com/)